# BackGroundWorker not executing on background

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

When I load my page, I can only navigate after the background worker process is done... should it execute on background as the name say?

here is the code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker _bgk = new BackgroundWorker();
        _bgk.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(DoWork_BackGroundWork);
        _bgk.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(WorkComplete_BackGroundWork);
        _bgk.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void DoWork_BackGroundWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 99999; i++)
        {
            Trace.Write("STILL EXECUTING BACKGROUND WORKER");
        }
    }

    private void WorkComplete_BackGroundWork(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Trace.Write("===================== BACKGROUND WORKER FINISHED ===================");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone having the same problem as I am... Here is a good solution that worked like a charm for me.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/AsyncMethodInvocation.aspx

And here is a solution that worked even better:

http://weblogs.asp.net/albertpascual/archive/2009/05/14/fire-and-forget-class-for-asp-net.aspx

Both tested

Answer (score 6):

`BackgroundWorker` doesn't work with ASP.NET very well.

On top of that, unless you like playing with fire, launching background threads leaves the possibility open that IIS can recycle your thread without you knowing.  It's best to not use this type of threading in an ASP.NET environment (not saying *ever*, but it can be tricky to get correct)

Comment: O, it works with ASP.NET alright. Just not like you would expect and not very useful.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Clarified my answer.  Just in case a coding masochist wanted to put one in to production.

Answer (score 2):

`BackgroundWorker` is only for Windows Forms, not for ASP.NET.

You are much better off not using any background threads in ASP.NET unless you are an expert in multithreading.

Comment: so, is there a way to do execute a piece of code on background? i just need a way to execute a method on background...

Comment: I urge you to find another way. Unless you really know what you're doing,  you can really mess things up badly.

Comment: don't you know any other way? or a suggestion? sorry, i have not that much experience on this matter...

Comment: If you plan to ask for advice from experts, then you would do well to listen to the advice you are given. Anyone sufficiently new to ASP.NET that he tries to use BackgroundWorker in an ASP.NET application is someone too new to be using multiple threads at all, much less in an ASP.NET application. If you were working for me, I would tell you to not use multiple threads until you know what you are doing.

Comment: well I definitely won't be using BackGroundWorker or Multiple Thread.  I just want to know if there is another way to archive this?

Comment: Yes, but if you use any of the other ways, you will screw up your program in ways that are difficult to debug. Beginners should never use multiple threads. I'm not going to bother with you anymore. Just give up and get over it. If you insist, I'm sure you can find someone here who will hand you the loaded gun to shoot yourself with. That person will not be me.

Answer (score 2):

The `BackgroundWorker` is only designed to work using `WindowsForms`.

If you want to simulate the same functinality, use a `Thread` instead, but be careful using threads in ASP.NET, ensure that what you're doing doesn't affect the client-server communication.

Answer (score 2):

and in the event you have to use threading, use the ThreadPool.QueueWorkerItem(...)